# Kotlin, instantiation issue and generic

Tags: kotlin

I have a class Vec3i that extends Vec3t

```
data class Vec3i(
  override var x: Int = 0,
  override var y: Int = 0,
  override var z: Int = 0
) : Vec3t(x, y, z)
```

that has as one secondary constructor as follow

```
constructor(v: Vec3t<Number>) : this(v.x.toInt(), v.y.toInt(), v.z.toInt())
```

and another class Vec3ub that extends always Vec3t

```
data class Vec3ub(
  override var x: Ubyte = Ubyte(0),
  override var y: Ubyte = Ubyte(0), 
  override var z: Ubyte = Ubyte(0)
) : Vec3t(x, y, z)
```

Where Vec3t is in turn

```
abstract class Vec3t<T : Number>(
  override var x: T, 
  override var y: T, 
  open var z: T
) : Vec2t(x, y)
```

And Ubyte extends Number

I'd like to instantiate a Vec3i from a Vec3ub

```
Vec3i(vec3ub)
```

but the compilers complains that there is no constructor for that..

why isn't valid the secondary constructor I quoted previously?

Comment: You should include the type parameters to make this a valid question. For example, `Vec3t` is missing the `T` type parameter. Also, the `constructor(v : Vec3t)` needs to have this parameter. If I correct the code with the needed type parameters, the code compiles correctly.

Comment: Sorry, they went lost when I wrote them on top of my head, I have them in the code but I get still the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, as stated in my comment, the following compiles correctly:

```
data class Vec3i(
        override var x: Int = 0,
        override var y: Int = 0,
        override var z: Int = 0
) : Vec3t<Int>(x, y, z) {

    constructor(v: Vec3t<out Number>) : this(v.x.toInt(), v.y.toInt(), v.z.toInt())
}

data class Vec3ub(
        override var x: Ubyte,
        override var y: Ubyte,
        override var z: Ubyte
) : Vec3t<Ubyte>(x, y, z)

abstract class Vec3t<T>(
        override var x: T,
        override var y: T,
        open var z: T
) : Vec2t<T>(x, y)

open class Vec2t<T>(
        open var x: T,
        open var y: T
)

fun test(vec3ub: Vec3ub) {
    val vec3i = Vec3i(vec3ub)
}

abstract class Ubyte : Number()
```

Note the `constructor(v : Vec3t<out Number>) : ...` and all other added generic parameter types. `Vec3t<out Number>` is necessary instead of just `Vec3t<Number>` here since you don't pass a `Number`, but rather a subclass of it.

Comment: The culprit was the `out` keyword.. I didn't get very well the difference between `in` and `out` from the doc, may you quickly clarify it in basic terms?

Comment: It is complicated, "quickly" doesn't apply.  http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html  ... best to ask this in forums, slack, etc. because it is a discussion and not a SO style question.